# Force iBooks on iOS to sync with iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, data-synchronization, books

I have my iBooks setup on both my iPhone and Mac so that their contents are always in sync. If I delete a book on my Mac, then it gets deleted on my iPhone, too. However, it usually takes 24 hours before it takes effect on the iPhone, after I delete a book on the Mac.

How can I force a sync on the iPhone so that updates are reflected immediately?

Comment: I have a similar problem with bookmarks in iBooks. These can go days (weeks) without syncing and then suddenly sync. There appears to be no rhyme or reason, nor is there [a way to force sync](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/334876/4395). I find Apple's could services are in generally pretty random and unreliable, and increasingly try to just avoid using them and switch to reliable alternatives when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that if I want to ADD a book, then it's best to add it on my Mac. Then wait until it uploads to iCloud, then after about a minute it will appear in iBooks on my iPhone. I then hit the iCloud icon next to the book title to download it.

If I want to delete a book, then I delete it from my iPhone rather than my Mac. It will then walk you through a few options, until you reach the point where you say that you want to delete the book from ALL iCloud devices. Then it will also delete it from your Mac, after about a minute.