# How do I force iBooks to sync highlights?

Tags: data-synchronization, books

My iBooks books are no longer syncing highlights between macOS and iOS. Highlights I've make on macOS are not appearing on iOS. How do I force this sync to occur?

Comment: How are you doing the sync?  What versions of macOS and iOS are you using?

Comment: @fsb What do you mean by how? Syncing is (meant to be) the default behavior.

Comment: You could be using iCloud or any other method of syncing.  That's what I meant.

Comment: @fsb I didn’t know there were other methods for syncing iBooks highlights. What are they?

Comment: Some people have used Dropbox or similar services.  I didn't want to assume how your were doing the sync because it wasn't specified in the question, that's all.

Comment: @fsb To sync iBooks highlighting? How?

Comment: I don't know, I never tried it. If you Google it you'll see people have done it. However, your question isn't about that so I don't want to get off on a tangent that's not related to your question.

Comment: Do you know that the devices in question are otherwise syncing iBooks? Could it be that one of the devices hasn’t synced at all?

Comment: @EJMak It could be that other things are not syncing either. But that just expands the question: how do I get iBooks to sync? When Apple's products go into these common long periods (hours days) where they decide not to sync some or all of their features, users a left in the lurch: there's no user feedback, not obvious way to force a sync, and critical information (an appointment in Calendar, an update phone number, etc.) can be missing from some devices. Google's products never seem to have this problem.

Comment: Can you verify that your iCloud settings on both devices have the iBooks app turned on?

Comment: @EJMak Yes. All configured correctly to sync everything on both ends.